# Does Akatsuki Nagisa knows that Akatsuki Kojou is the Fouth Progenitor?

Tags: strike-the-blood

Title says it all. Does Akatsuki Kojou's imouto (little sister) knows that his oniichan (elder brother) is the Fourth Progenitor? If yes, since when she knows that? In the 24 episodes of the anime, it doesn't seems like Nagisa knows. What about the light novel?

Comment: _She is the only main character who knows nothing about the supernatural incidents as the others conceal such information to protect her_,

[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strike_the_Blood) it states that

Comment: is it really necessary to write their relationship in romanji? I'm tempted to edit the post and remove the Japanese since it also looks like there are some grammar problems and maybe a wrong pronoun? All in all its pretty confusing on the first read through.

Comment: edit: romanji is supposed to be [romaji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese)

Comment: Go ahead if you think that is for the best. I don't mind.